# поиск по полю varchar

Tags: mysql

Есть база данных MySql. Есть таблица Task. Есть varchar поле 'executors_id'. В нём через запятую перечисляются id исполнителей задачи. Могут быть записи типа '1' или '1,178,202' или '2,33' и т.д.

Каким запросом можно выбрать все задачи конкретного исполнителя, к примеру с id == 1 и не вытянуть лишнего, к примеру задачи исполнителя 178?

Comment: Лучше подумать о правильной структуре базы данных, пользователи отдельно список задач отдельно, понимаю может быть сложно первое время, но лучше сразу привыкать к хорошему, чтобы потом меньше мучиться.

Comment: ```.. WHERE FIND_IN_SET( $id , executors_id ) ..```. Но полностью согласен с предыдущим оратором - срочно уходи от этого бреда в сторону нормальных форм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве прямого ответа на вопрос предлагаю использовать регулярные выражения. `'^1,|,1,|,1$|^1$'`  тут мы ищем 1 во всех случаях:

- `^1,` - в начале строки 1 и далее другие числа
- `,1,` - где-то в середине строки
- `,1$` - последнее число в строке 1
- `^1$` - единственное число и это 1

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Tasks (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    Users VARCHAR (255)
);


INSERT INTO Tasks (Name, Users)
VALUES
    ("Footbal", '1'),
    ("Cooking", '178,1,202'),
    ("Shopping", '12,33');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * from Tasks WHERE (SELECT Users  REGEXP '^1,|,1,|,1$|^1$')=1;
```

| id | Name | Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Footbal | 1 |
| 2 | Cooking | 178,1,202 |

---

**Вариант с изменением структуры БД**

На счет Вашей версии MySQL не уверен, но я побыстрому накидал как бы я организовывал таблицы. Разумеется, имена таблиц - дело вкуса. Возможно упустил какие-то моменты, так как редко пишу `SQL`, но думаю основную суть смог передать — в журнале содержаться пары `задача - пользователь` и они могут быть любыми валидными парами, т.е. на одну задачу может быть несколько пользователей и наоборот, но каждая запись отвечает за одну связь. Надеюсь Вам это поможет.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Tasks (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Journal (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TaskID INT,
    UserID INT,
    INDEX ts_ind (TaskID),
    INDEX us_ind (UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (TaskID) REFERENCES Tasks(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(id) 
);

INSERT INTO Users (Name)
VALUES
    ("Peter"),
    ("Masha");


INSERT INTO Tasks (Name)
VALUES
    ("Footbal"),
    ("Cooking"),
    ("Shopping");


INSERT INTO Journal (TaskID, UserID)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  Tasks.Name as task, 
  Users.Name as user 
FROM 
  Journal 
  LEFT JOIN Users ON Journal.UserID = Users.id 
  LEFT JOIN Tasks ON Journal.TaskID = Tasks.id 
WHERE 
  UserID = 1;
```

| task | user |
| --- | --- |
| Footbal | Peter |
| Shopping | Peter |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: С регулярками - это было сильно...